# ¿Como puedo hacer que cada usuario tenga sus propias listas de pedido que inicializen en 1,2,3.. etc..?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Quisiera saber como hacer que en cada pedido que haga un determinado usuario este tenga su historial de pedidos y que no compartan por ejemplo:

El autoincrementable de otros usuarios,osea que si un usuario x hace 10 pedidos , que no se muestre al otro usuario que ha creado un pedido empiece en 11 el id ,ya que, esos espacios ya fueron rellenados por otro usuario.

No se si me explico, esto es más teoría ya que no comprendo como poder hacerlo,me refiero a pedido cuando un cliente compra varios productos ,entonces creo una linea de pedido  y este se guarda en la tabla, pero aqui esta el problema, que otro usuario puede llegar y crear por ej: 5 pedidos y otro usuario x cuando quiera crear un pedido mas estaria empezando el id en 6 ya que fueron ocupados los 5 espacios,eso quiero evitar y que empiece en un 1, porque se guardan en una sola tabla los todos las lineas de pedidos de todos los usuarios,se agradecería muchisimo que puedan explicarme la lógica para evitar esto.

Principalmente es una pregunta de base de datos de como poder evitar esto.

(Pero lo desarrollo con php)

(Comprendo también que esta pregunta no cumple los requisitos para ser publicada,ya que, puede ser extenso) pero me gustaria saber bastante como hacer esto.(Srry si es mucho texto,intente detallarlo lo mas que pude,para que se comprenda)

Comment: El problema es pensar que el id autoincremental se puede usar para algo, y ese es el error. NO, el id autoincremental es solo para ubicar mas rapido un registro (para usarlo como clave). Por favor, usa un metodo por el cual tengas ademas el numero secuencial de pedido, el cual vas a tener que ubicar y conseguir vos. No podes usar un autoincremental para eso. Ademas, el autoincremental, no llena agujeros y hasta puede tener baches.

Comment: @gbianchi Claro, el "ocupa agujeros" fue mas que nada una expresion , es que resulta que es algo más visual que relacionado a la funcionalidad.

Comment: no no. No lo entendiste, la mayoria de las db no asegura que el autoincremental no deje agujeros en si mismo..

Comment: @gbianchi Aaah okey comprendo , no sabia ese detalle, gracias gbanchi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer un count de los pedidos del usuario justo antes de crear uno nuevo, no hay forma de resolver eso con un autoincremental

Comment: Gracias amigo! Me diste una idea clara de como hacerlo.!